# Using ArcGIS Field Maps (Offline Capabilities) on a Samsung Galaxy Mobile Tablet for Field Use

Tags: arcgis-online, offline, arcgis-field-maps

I'm setting up Field Maps for my organization including a workflow document. I am pretty familiar with the offline capability of Field Maps. However, I was asked an interesting question by my program lead, that is, can we save our data, and upload to a laptop directly, all while offline. To my current knowledge that this is not possible as you have to wait until there is connectivity (Wi-Fi or cell service) and then sync all your changes.

What my program manager was trying to get at though, was the ability, for instance, with a Trimble Geo7x unit (running Terra Sync) to upload data, daily, without the need for connectivity. Is there perhaps a way to save edits to layers, etc., directly to the device or to a micro SD card on the device? The concern mainly stems from the fact that we might be in the field (backcountry setting with no service) for several days at a time and desire to upload the data to a computer every night.

Has anyone had experience with this at all?

Comment: We've had several occasions where a sync has failed (using Collector) where we've hooked our iPads up directly to a computer and downloaded the packaged info, along with the changes on the iPad. I don't know if this would be the same with a Samsung, but it is definitely possible to take a backup. I don't know about reading it from there though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Just wanted to clarify, what did you mean by reading it from there? In your experience, were you able to download these files as shapefiles or in a similar format?

Comment: It has been a long time since I've had to do so. Looking at them it seems they are geodatabases. Again, this was Collector so may be different for Field Maps. All I know (and have time to research) is that there is a way for Collector, but from what I've seen both Collector and Field Maps are pretty interchangeable.